# Ant build file on windows where on earth do I put {sdk.dir} definition?

Tags: android, build

I have an ant build file:

when I run ant build I get com.android.setupTask cannot be found?

What am I missing?  How exactly do I specify {sdk.dir} in windows. Its no where in any file? Is this the cause of the error message?  How can I see what {sdk.dir} is currently set to? How can I show this on windows. There is no echo.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass it at the command line as follows

```
ant -Dsdk.dir=path/to/android/sdk/root/dir -Dtarget=targeted-android-sdk-version
```

Comment: You should also ensure that the "path/to/android/sdk/root/dir" is in your path.

Answer (score -1):

I just googled this one for you.

[http://blog.klacansky.com/matter-code/ant-taskdef-class-com-android-ant-setuptask-cannot-be-
found](http://blog.klacansky.com/matter-code/ant-taskdef-class-com-android-ant-setuptask-cannot-be-found)

Does this helps?